# Fill up missing datetime with NaN or supress straight line in line plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have problems with getting my plot look like I want it to look using matplotlib.
I have aggregated data (Y) as float corresponding to dates (X) as datetime64 format. My data starts on 2019/04/23 and ends on 2019/08/02. Unfortunately, the data is not complete, I'm missing a period between 2019/06/18 and 2019/07/08.

This leads to a straight line between those two dates in my plot, which I want to disappear.

I know one possibility would be to fill up the missing dates and times and the column LEVEL with NaN using pandas. As I read, matplotlib will ignore the the NaN so my problem would be solved?
If so, how can I do this in my case? I tried out a lot of code snippets already, e.g. using the DATETIME as a Index (which I would like to avoid in order to not screw up the following code).

Another possibility: Maybe there is a strategy to just suppress this line while plotting without touching the data frame? Not clean, but would be efficient enough. Yes, a scatter plot with points would be a way to avoid the line, but I need it like this.

Here an example of how my dataframe looks like:

```
      DATETIME     LEVEL
0     2019-04-23 16:30:00  0.087074
1     2019-04-23 16:35:00  0.093089
2     2019-04-23 16:40:00  0.081103
3     2019-04-23 16:45:00  0.093117
4     2019-04-23 16:50:00  0.093131
5     2019-04-23 16:55:00  0.087145
6     2019-04-23 17:00:00  0.087159
7     2019-04-23 17:05:00  0.087174
8     2019-04-23 17:10:00  0.087188
```

You can see the line between the two vertical red and green lines, which have another meaning.

[image]

Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: you want to exclude it from the axis? or just have blanks?

Comment: I don't know of a way to not connect it in a line plot. I'd plot the two sides separately.

Comment: You can add an extra date, e.g 2019-06-25 in your dataframe and set its value in the level column to nan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have your example data frame but with the three rows in the middle missing:

```
In [65]: df
Out[65]: 
             DATETIME     LEVEL
0 2019-04-23 16:30:00  0.087074
1 2019-04-23 16:35:00  0.093089
2 2019-04-23 16:40:00  0.081103
3 2019-04-23 17:00:00  0.087159
4 2019-04-23 17:05:00  0.087174
5 2019-04-23 17:10:00  0.087188
```

Now we can fill those missing values by indexing the DataFrame with the `DATETIME` column and then `resample()` that.  Afterwards we kann reset the index again to turn the index back into a normal column again:

```
In [66]: df.set_index('DATETIME').resample('5min').first().reset_index()
Out[66]: 
             DATETIME     LEVEL
0 2019-04-23 16:30:00  0.087074
1 2019-04-23 16:35:00  0.093089
2 2019-04-23 16:40:00  0.081103
3 2019-04-23 16:45:00       NaN
4 2019-04-23 16:50:00       NaN
5 2019-04-23 16:55:00       NaN
6 2019-04-23 17:00:00  0.087159
7 2019-04-23 17:05:00  0.087174
8 2019-04-23 17:10:00  0.087188
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is the closest to what I wanted, not only because it's useful to fill up the rows in order to do statistical analysis with it. However, I ended up creating a new dataframe filled completely with NaN, creating the dates and using them as index directly. I then added my data afterwards with combine_first().

Answer (score -1):

You just need to plot two lines instead of one.
Divide the dataset where you need it and plot them separately.
Here a simple example with two straight line

```py
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[5,5,5,5])
plt.plot([7,8,9,10],[6,6,6,6])
plt.show()
```

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFnlq.png)